# Problems spawning a multi-threaded process from a separate single-threaded process in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, process, openmp

I've had some rather unusual behavior from my OpenMP program, which I think must be caused by some inner-workings of Linux processes that I am unaware of.

When I run a C benchmark binary which has been compiled with OpenMP support, the program executes successfully, no problems at all:

```
>:$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-3" /home/me/bin/benchmark
>:$ ...benchmark complete...
```

When I run the benchmark from a separate C++ program that I start, where the code to execute it (for example) looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    system("/home/me/bin/benchmark");

    return 0;
}
```

The output gives me warnings:

```
>:$ home/me/bin/my_cpp_program
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 1.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 2.
OMP: Warning #123: Ignoring invalid OS proc ID 3.
```

These warnings are the **same warnings** I get when I try to set CPU affinity to CPUs that don't exist, and run the OpenMP benchmark directly.

I therefore assume that the only CPU `my_cpp_program` knows to exist is processor ID 0. I also get the same error when using root so I don't think it is a permissions problem? I've also checked that the code executed by `system()` has the correct environment variables, and the same linked libraries.

Does anyone know what is causing this to occur?

Comment: How about passing threading parameters as command-line arguments instead of env variables?

Comment: I thought the same so I tried that but no cigar. It doesn't seem to be those environment variables either because I can change them and the warnings adjust accordingly (i.e. it complains about whatever processors I specify).

Comment: I've actually made doubly sure by printing the results of "env" to file from the program, then in interactive mode, running source on that file before running my binary, and it works fine. So I think it has to be something more magical than the environment variables. I wonder if i can get gdb to debug the spawned process...

Comment: Please provide the compilation lines, and compiler versions used for **both** programs. Did you reproduce the issue with the specific "for example" code you posted? Please also provide a minimal example for the "benchmark" program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a suggestion by Zulan, I'm pretty sure the reason this occurred was because of the nature and compilation of `bin/my_cpp_program`. It was importantly **also** compiled with `-fopenmp`. It turns out that `bin/my_cpp_program` was compiled against the GNU OpenMP implementation library `libgomp`, whereas the `bin/benchmark` program was compiled against the LLVM OpenMP implementation library `libomp`.

I am not certain, but what I think happened was the following. `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITIY` is the GNU environment variable for setting CPU affinity in `libgomp`. Therefore because `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` was set, the single-thread running in `bin/my_cpp_program` was bound to CPU 0. I guess any child processes spawned by that thread must also only see CPU 0 as its potential-CPUs when using further `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` affinity assignments. This then gave me the warnings when the spawned process (from the environment) tries to find CPUs 1-3.

To workaround this I used `KMP_AFFINITY` which is Intel's CPU affinity environment variable. The `libomp` OpenMP runtime used by `bin/benchmark` gives a higher precedence to `KMP_AFFINITY` when both it and `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` are set, and for whatever reason this allows the spawned child process to assign to other CPUs. So to do this, I used:

```
KMP_AFFINITY=logical,granularity=fine ./bin/benchmark
```

This means the program works as expected (each logical core is bound in ascending order from 0 to 3) in **both** situations, as the CPU assignments of the `bin/my_cpp_program` no longer screw with the assignments of `bin/benchmark`, when one spawns the other. This can be checked as truly occurring by adding `verbose` to the comma-separated list.